# Passing variable to a macro in Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have made some small macro that I am using to display text line and label for it:

```
{% macro input(name, text, help_text, value="", input_type) -%}
    <label for="id_{{name}}">{{text}}<span class="right">{{help_text}}</span></label>
    <input id="id_{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" type="{{input_type}}" />
{{%- endmacro %}
```

The problem is when I call jinja2 macro:

```
{{input("username", "Korisničko ime:", "Pomoć", {{value_username}}, "text")}
```

I can't get it to work when I call input with `{{value_username}}` as parameter, I always get an error.

Do you know any solution how can I call `{{value_username}}` as parameter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe

```
{{ input("username", "Korisničko ime:", "Pomoć", value_username, "text") }}
```

should work

Comment: Thanks, it works great even with filter.
But, if there is other strings append or prepped to the variable, (for example =>  "Hello {{ value_username | capitalize }}, good morning!"), is it possible to pass this kind of string to macro? I'm trying to avoid make whole strings being a single variable, because there are many prepped and append combinations.

Comment: @正宗白布鞋 you can do `"Hello " + value_username | capitalize + ", good morning!"`

Answer (score 4):

Although Emmett J. Butler has provided an answer, there's a small nitpick with the ordering of  macro parameters. You currently use following signature:

```
input(name, text, help_text, value="", input_type)
```

You should always put the arguments containing default value after all the other required arguments, therefore changing the order into this:

```
input(name, text, help_text, input_type, value="")
```

Now when calling macros with variables as arguments, you don't need to surround your variables with `{{ }}` because you are already inside the `{% ... %}`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this with dot-notation variables (`data.datapoint`), you have to do `data['datapoint']` instead and it will work. You can also apply filters to the datapoint.