# Jinja loop variable as macro variable?

Tags: sql, macros, jinja2, dbt

I have the following loop in a dbt-spark model:

```
{% for day_hour in day_hours %}
     , {{ get_time(3, '{{day_hour}}') }} AS open_{{day_hour}}
{% endfor %}
```

Where day_hours is a list of integers from 0 to 23 (already defined) and get_time is a macro defined as

```
{% macro generate_timestamp(days, hours) %}
     DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '{{ days }}' day) + interval '{{ hours }}' hour
{% endmacro %}
```

The problem is that in the call to the macro the {{ day_hour }} appears as a string as it is written, instead of returning the corresponding number. If I remove the single quotes around {{ day_hours }} it throws a compilation error.

However, In the second call to {{ day_hour }} within the loop:

```
AS open_{{day_hour}}
```

It works perfectly.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the loop variable as macro parameter??

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variable to a macro in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163904/passing-variable-to-a-macro-in-jinja2)

Answer (score 1):

[Don't nest your curlies.](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies)

Your call to `get_time` is already wrapped in curlies, so you can just write `day_hour` to reference the jinja variable:

```
{% for day_hour in day_hours %}
     , {{ get_time(3, day_hour) }} AS open_{{day_hour}}
{% endfor %}
```